# Approximating e-bits by CHSH black boxes

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics, quantum-games

In the CHSH game two parties Alice and Bob independently get a bit $x$ and $y$ which is $0$ or $1$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$.

Without communicating each of them has to send a referee a bit $a$ and $b$ and they win the game if
$$
a \oplus b = \min(x,y) 
$$
Here $\oplus$ is the XOR or sum mod 2.

It is quite easy to see that the maximal win probability of this game is $\frac{3}{4}$.

Now, the magic of the game is that if Alice and Bob share an e-bit, which is a two qubit maximally entangled state
$$\vert \psi \rangle = \frac{\vert 00 \rangle + \vert 11 \rangle}{\sqrt{2}}  
$$ that they are allowed to due measurements on, then they can increase their win probabilities to $\cos^2 \left(\frac{\pi}{8} \right) \approx 85 \% $ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CHSH_inequality for an explanation of what all of this means).

If you do not know about the measurements and what this means one can interpret this game as a black box that correlates bits in that way and then try to use it for other quantum games. Clearly, if you have an e-bit then you can also get a black box, but what about the other way around?

To what extend one can use many of these black boxes to simulate an e-bit?

In the sense that if you have some scheme for measuring the e-bit can you use many CSHS black boxes to get approximately the same result?

A more precise way to formulate this could be suppose that Alice and Bob can win a quantum game $Q$ with probability $a$ using some number of e-bits. For any $\varepsilon > 0$ does there then exist a number of CHSH blackboxes so that they can win the same game with probability $a- \varepsilon$?

Comment: simulate in what sense? if the black box can only operate locally on Alice and Bob, then obviously it cannot "simulate" entanglement; you may want to specify what you allow for the black box.

Comment: The word ‘e-bit’ does not seem to appear in the linked Wiki article.  What does it mean?

Comment: @LSpice ---  the "e" in e-bit stands for "entanglement" : Alice and Bob share a bipartite state with one unit of entanglement entropy